# Use power series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac {z^{n+1}} {n(n+1)}$ to show $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac {1} {n(n+1)} =1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Consider $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac {z^{n+1}} {n(n+1)}$ (power series). I've found that the sum-function $g(z) := \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac {z^{n+1}} {n(n+1)}$ is defined and continuous on $|z| \le 1$.

Let $f$ be the restriction of $g$ to $[-1,1]$. I've shown that $f(x) = (1-x)\log(1-x)+x$.

How can I use these results to show $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac {1} {n(n+1)} =1$ ?

I'm well aware that $\frac 1 n - \frac 1 {n+1} = \frac 1 {n(n+1)}$, but I think I should use what I've proved instead of looking at the partial sums.

Does it hold to say $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} (1-x)\log(1-x)+x$  ? I know, since $f$ is continuous $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} f(x) = f(1)$, but $(1-x)\log(1-x)+x$ is not defined for $x=1$ ?

Comment: See the technical details at Baby Rudin, Theorem 8.2.

Comment: show that $\lim_{x \to 1}(1-x)\log(1-x)=0$ using, e.g. L'Hospital's rule or expand in Macluarin series. Hence your expression $\to 1$

Comment: Yes my expression for $f(x)$ not defined for $1$ has limit $1$. This implies $f(x)$ has limit $1$ also, right ?

Comment: how can I use L'Hospital's rule, when the expression is not a fraction ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

When $x$ goes to $0$, $x\log(x)$ has a limit of $0$ and, so, when $x$ goes to $1$, $(1-x)\log(1-x)$ has also a limit of $0$.

Comment: But what if this limit doesn't equal $f(1)$ ? I mean there is functions which limit values at a point doesn't correspond to the value of the function at the point ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the important missing ingredient is [Abel's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem). This is also used, for example, to prove that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac1n = \log 2.$$